# Enable ClearType with Linux remote desktop

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, fonts

I know that you can enable font smoothing (ClearType) when connecting to a Windows machine using Windows Remote Desktop client, but can't find a corresponding option in Linux one (`rdesktop`).

Is it possible and, if yes, how can it be done?

Comment: I tested the proposed solution and it works - I suggest to give him a pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not officially supported, but apparently there's a [hidden option t](http://katastrophos.net/andre/blog/2008/03/10/rdesktop-connect-to-windows-vista-with-cleartype-font-smoothing-enabled/)o get it working - with a command like

> rdesktop -x 0x80 mywinserver

to use the lan default with cleartype

More details on the linked page including the commands for using cleartype with other defaults.

Comment: Perfect well working solution (tested between recent debian-based linux distro in 2016 and win7).